# How to pass SOAP Header parameters in a Worklight SOAP adapter procedure?

Tags: java, soap, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

I have used the IBM MobileFirst Studio V7.1 - Service Discovery wizard option and created a SOAP adapter from a application WSDL file. The Service Discovery procedure correctly creates the MobileFirst adapter in the MFP Studio

The message payload is shown below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns1:Security soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
         <ns1:UsernameToken>
            <ns1:Username>IBM</ns1:Username>
            <ns1:Password>IBM</ns1:Password>
         </ns1:UsernameToken>
      </ns1:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cus:QueryJobDetails_Input>
         <cus:Object_spcId>SURV0332</cus:Object_spcId>
      </cus:QueryJobDetails_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, using the adapter testing option in the MobileFirst Studio, the following JSON payload are being passed in the dialog window

**Procedure Arguments**

params :

```
{"QueryJobDetails_Input":{"Object_spcId":"SURV0332"}}
```

headers:

```
{"UsernameToken":{"Username":"IBM","Password":"IBM"}}
```

But I get the following error when the adapter executes

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Class Cast: com.worklight.common.js.util.JSObjectConverter$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Is the WS Security Header block being passed in the correct format ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format for parameters is different from that of headers.  You have the right format for parameters.  For headers it needs to be JSON containing only a list of keys and values.  Please see the following documentation:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_invocation_generated_soap_adapter.html?lang=en